# AWS Sagemaker Notebook with multiple users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am still new in AWS sagemaker. Working on a architecture where we would have an AWS sagemaker notebook. There would be multiple users, I want that students don`t see each other work. would I need to do that in terminal? or we can do that in notebook itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a small notebook instance for each student. This way you can have the needed isolation and also the responsibility of each student for their notebook to stop them when they are not in use.

The smallest instance type [costs](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) $0.0464 per hour. If you have it running 24/7 it costs about $30 per month. But if the students are responsible and stop their instances when they are not using them, it can be about $1 for 20 hours of work.

If you want to enable isolation to the notebooks, you can use the ability to presign the URL that is used to open the Jupyter interface. See here on the way to use the CLI to create the URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-notebook-instance-url.html. It is also supported in other SDK.

```
create-presigned-notebook-instance-url
--notebook-instance-name <student-instance-name>
--session-expiration-duration-in-seconds 3600
```

You can integrate it into the internal portal that you have in your institute.

Comment: how we can control that student do not able to see each other notebook?

Comment: @JaishreeMishra, I've updated the answer above with the instructions to use presigned-url